# How to get json data for passing it by segue

Tags: ios, json, swift, urlsession

I try to get json data while `URLSession.dataTask` is running to set segue .(each json data as sender)

So First, I made my own Class Array `productList = [Product]()`.
Next, I call `getJsonData()` and inside of that, I set `URLSession.dataTask` method. So I got Parsed json data. However, When I try to save that json data(append each data to `productList`) from `dataTask completionHandler`, it cannot save correctly.(result `productList` is `[]`)

I want to pass parsed json data by segue. How can I do this?

edited --

```
class MainVC: UITableViewController {

    var productList = [Product]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getJsonData()

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return productList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as? ItemCell {
            let product = productList[indexPath.row]

            cell.configureCell(product)

            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }


    func getJsonData() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://demo7367352.mockable.io")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)


        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            do {
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print("network request failed: error = \(error)")
                    return
                }

                guard let rawItem = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    return
                }


                if let fineItem = rawItem["goods"] as? [[String:Any]] {

                    for item in fineItem {
                        let eachProduct = Product(title: "", price: 0)

                        let title = item["TITLE"]
                        let price = item["PRICE"]
                        let regDate = item["REGDATE"]
                        let description = item["DESCRIPTION"]
                        let iconURL = item["ICON_URL"]
                        let images = item["IMAGES"]


                        if let title = title as? String {
                            eachProduct.title = title
                        }
                        if let price = price as? String {
                            eachProduct.price = Int(price)!
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            self.productList.append(eachProduct)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
                    }

                }

            } catch  {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
            }

        })
        task.resume()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToProductDetail" {
            if let controller = segue.destination as? DetailVC, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Right now, I can parse datas from `URLSession DataTask`. I want to implement segue of tableView to show detail. But `productList` is empty. So I cannot use `prepareForSegue` with `productList[indexPath.row]`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToProductDetail" {
        if let controller = segue.destination as? DetailVC, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            controller.product = productList[indexPath.row] // productList is nil.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say that `productList` is empty. You later say that it is `nil`. But aren't you showing `productList` in the table view?!? Isn't `cellFor` successfully using `productList`? So how can it be empty? We're either not talking about the the same `productList` or you're resetting it somewhere. But we can't diagnose this on the basis of the information provided. Perhaps show us precisely how/where you diagnosed that `productList` was empty/`nil`. (Note, an empty array and `nil` are two completely different things and given how you declared it, it can't be `nil` ... it's not an optional.)

Comment: @Rob Oh, Sorry. I tried it again, and it works. There was an Xcode bug about it. Anyway Thank you for your careful answer. Next time I need to explain my situation with more detail and precise words. I will change my post with answer. Thanks.

Comment: Don't edit your question to include answer. Instead, post a separate answer to your own question. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Rob Ok, Thanks. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare) and pass the data there:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let controller = segue.destination as? MySecondViewController, indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        controller.product = productList[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

The exact syntax will vary (what is the class name of your destination view controller) and you'd have to declare that `product` property in the destination, and the destination's `viewDidLoad` would need to use that property, but hopefully it illustrates the basic idea.

---

Some additional observations:

1. I'd suggest you inspect `rawItem` and make sure it's a dictionary that has a key called `goods` and that the value associated with that key is really an array of dictionaries. Without seeing your JSON, it's impossible to say what exactly is going wrong.

   Also, consider:

   ```
   if let fineItem = rawItem["goods"] as? [[String:Any]] {
       ...
   }
   ```

   If that fails, you'll never know. I might instead suggest:

   ```
   guard let fineItem = rawItem["goods"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
       print("goods not found or wrong type")
       return
   }
   ...
   ```
2. BTW, and unrelated to your problem at hand, it's a little dangerous to be mutating `productList` directly in the completion handler of your data task. Don't asynchronously mutate arrays from one thread that are read from another thread. Arrays are not thread-safe. The data task completion handler should build a local array and only when it's done, inside where you're dispatching the reload to the main queue, you should insert code to replace the `productList` with your local array before the table is reloaded.
3. Also, you're currently calling `reloadData` inside the parsing loop. You'd generally call it at the end of the parsing loop. Right now, if your data set had 100 rows, you'd be reloading the table 100 times.
4. The reference to `data!` is a bit dangerous. If you have no internet connection, `data` will be `nil` and your code will crash. I'd suggest:

   ```
   guard let data = data, error == nil else {
       print("network request failed: error = \(error)")
       return
   }
   ```

   And then you can replace the `data!` reference with `data`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I follow your suggestions. But the problem is I can see whole item from table, But `productList` is empty. So I can not access data from `prepareForSegue` by `productList[indexPath.row]`.

Comment: Like I said elsewhere, I don't understand what you mean by "I can see whole item from table" and "`productList` is empty". If (a) your table view is showing `productList` entries; and (b) you're seeing data in your table view; then how can (c) `productList` be empty? When you say "I can see whole item from table", where precisely are you seeing this? Edit your question, showing us what you see. This is very unclear.

Comment: I edited my question with simulator images and extra codes. Can you see that one more time?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't posting all of your code, but I believe that your mistake is that you are performing an asynchronous task and then immediately calling print on the array being modified. I wouldn't expect the array to be populated until the task is complete.

Does your tableView actually populate with results? Are you printing out the JSON to ensure that your data is matching properly? Are the errors being printed?

Edit:
To pass your data along the segue you need to retrieve your `destinationViewController` as a variable and pass the information to it. There is a method called `prepareForSegue` that allows you to handle the preliminary state before your action happens.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   let vc = segue.destination as! ExampleVC
   vc.setProducts(productList)
}
```

Something like that. Obviously changing your class and variable names

Comment: Yes, tableview show result correctly. And I didn't write some code like numberOfRowsInSection, cause it will make my question too long.

Comment: Okay. I will edit my answer since it seems you have your data then.

Comment: @Rob Sorry for my ambiguous answer. The meaning of "I can show data correctly" means I can see data from table, But `productList` is not be updated.

Comment: @ChangnamHong - I can't reconcile "I can see data from table" (which I interpret as "my table view shows the `productList` retrieved from `getJsonData` in `MainVC`") and "`productList` is not ... updated". How can `productList` not be updated if you're seeing it successfully in your table view. Please clarify precisely what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Problem and here is my final code.

```
class MainVC: UITableViewController {

    var productList = [Product]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getJsonData()

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return productList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as? ItemCell {
            let product = productList[indexPath.row]

            cell.configureCell(product)

            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    // parsing
    func getJsonData() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://demo7367352.mockable.io")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)


        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            do {
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print("network request failed: error = \(error)")
                    return
                }
                guard let rawItem = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    return
                }
                guard let fineItem = rawItem["goods"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
                    print("goods not found or wrong type")
                    return
                }

                for item in fineItem {
                    let eachProduct = Product(title: "", price: 0)

                    let title = item["TITLE"]
                    let price = item["PRICE"]


                    if let title = title as? String {
                        eachProduct.title = title
                    }
                    if let price = price as? String {
                        eachProduct.price = Int(price)!
                    }

                    self.productList.append(eachProduct)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            } catch  {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
            }

        })
        task.resume()
    }

    // segue
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToProductDetail" {
            if let controller = segue.destination as? DetailVC, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                controller.product = productList[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
}
```